# Debug Assertion Failed - Array Iterators Incompatible

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, intersection, set-intersection

I am trying to get the intersection of an array and a vector. I decided to make them both vectors because it's how cplusplus.com gives an example.

This is the error message I get:

[image]

and here is my code:

[image]

the `getNumbers()` function returns an array.

**EDIT**

Here is the `getNumbers()` function - it just returns a property of the same return type:

[image]

Comment: Can we see `getNumbers`? If it's returning a copy of the numbers, that would explain the error.

Answer (score 3):

This assertion usually means that the iterators supplied as the beginning and the end of a range reference different collections.

> the `getNumbers()` function returns an array.

Unless `getNumbers()` returns an array by reference, and also returns the reference to the same array, this initialization is invalid:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> ticketNumbers(getNumbers().begin(), getNumbers().end());
```

In order for the above to work, `getNumbers()` must repeatedly return a reference to the same array. Your `getNumbers` returns a copy, because it returns an array by value.

To fix this line, first call `getNumbers()`, store the result in a temporary variable `tempNumbers`, like this

```
std::array<unsigned int, TICKET_BALL_COUNT> tempNumbers= getNumbers();
std::vector<unsigned int> ticketNumbers(tempNumbers.begin(), tempNumbers.end());
```

Alternatively, you could change your `getNumbers()` function to return a `const` reference, like this:

```
const std::array<unsigned int, TICKET_BALL_COUNT>& Ticket::getNumbers() const {
    return _numbers;
}
```

Comment: @AdamCarter You are welcome! Take a look at the second alternative, it could work too, and it would reduce the amount of copying.

Comment: That works nicely too, thanks. I'm new to C++ and it seems odd to have a const keyword either side of the function name? Is this standard practise?

Comment: @AdamCarter The two `const` keywords mean entirely different things, because they are attached to different elements of your code. The `const` in the beginning says that the reference the function returns is `const`, letting the callers read from the array, but not write to it. The `const` at the end says that the function itself does not modify the `Ticket` object of which it is a member-function. This determines whether or not you can call `getNumbers` on a `const Ticket myConstTicket` object: without a `const` at the end, a call like `myConstTicket.getNumbers()` would be illegal.